# Нужно сделать простейший чат-бот. Не получается правильное срабатывание бота на любое сочетание слов из предложенного списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, как решить такую задачу, пожалуйста!
Нужен тестовый бот. Он должен выполнить print('Ну, тогда до свидания!'), если на вопрос "Чем Вам помочь?: " пользователь ответит  любыми словами из списка 'ни', 'чем', 'не', 'нужно', 'сам', 'справлюсь', 'деньгами', 'помоги', 'материально', причём важно, чтобы он реагировал на эти слова, или на набор из этих слов, в любом сочетании. Т.е. и "ни" , и "ни чем", и "справлюсь сам", и "помоги деньгами", и "не сам".
Иначе, если ни одного из этих слов в ответе нет, то print('Я тебя не понимаю')
При одном из вариантов ответа бот переходит на блок, в котором опять задаёт вопрос, на который существует 2 варианта ответов. По той же схеме, из списка слов. Мой вариант решения работает только, когда последовательность слов из списка не нарушается. Вот блок-схема бота. В моём решении бот работает правильно, только если слова в ответе идут подряд.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
print('Тестовый бот для работы по "ключевикам"')
answer = input("Чем Вам помочь?: ")
if answer.lower() in ['ни', 'чем', 'не', 'нужно', 'сам', 'справлюсь', 'деньгами', 'помоги', 'материально']:
    print('Ну, тогда до свидания!')
elif answer.lower() in ['какой', 'язык', 'ты', 'знаешь', 'на', 'каком', 'языке', 'разговариваешь']:
    question = input('Я знаю только "Python". Задавай вопросы: ')
    if question.lower() in ['кто', 'тебя', 'создал', 'придумал', 'твой', 'создатель']:
        print('Знакомый')
    elif question.lower() in ['что', 'ты', 'умеешь', 'что', 'ты', 'можешь']:
        print('Я только учусь!')
else:
    print('Я тебя не понимаю')
```

Answer (score 4):

Вы проверяете, что введенный текст находится среди списка слов. А нужно наоборот проверять, что любое из слов входит во введенный текст:

```
words = ['ни', 'чем', 'не', 'нужно', 'сам', 'справлюсь', 'деньгами', 'помоги', 'материально']
answer = input("Чем Вам помочь?: ").lower()

if any(word in answer for word in words):
    print('Ну, тогда до свидания!')
else:
    print('Я тебя не понимаю')
```

Вообще, лучше работать не на уровне отдельных слов, а на уровне фраз. То есть проверять, не что во фразе есть какие-то слова, а что введена именно конкретная фраза:

```
answer = input("Чем Вам помочь?: ").lower()

if answer in ['ни чем', 'ничем', 'не нужно', 'сам справлюсь', 'деньгами', 'помоги материально']:
    print('Ну, тогда до свидания!')
else:
    print('Я тебя не понимаю')
```

Для удобства можно выделить в отдельную функцию, и еще убирать из текста все лишнее (дублирующиеся пробелы, знаки препинания и т.д.), в данном случае сделано через регулярные выражения:

```
import re


def check_phrases(text: str, phrases: list):
    # получить набор слов без дублирующихся пробелов и без знаков препинания
    text = " ".join(re.findall(r"\w+", text.lower()))  # Если очистка не нужна - убрать эту строку
    
    return text in phrases


answer = input("Чем Вам помочь?: ")
if check_phrases(answer, ["ни чем", "ничем", "не нужно", "сам справлюсь", "деньгами", "помоги материально", "материально"]):
    print('Ну, тогда до свидания!')
elif check_phrases(answer, ['какой язык ты знаешь', 'какой язык знаешь', 'на каком языке разговариваешь', 'на каком языке ты разговариваешь']):
    question = input('Я знаю только "Python". Задавай вопросы: ')
    if check_phrases(question, ['кто тебя создал', 'кто тебя придумал', 'кто твой создатель']):
        print('Знакомый')
    elif check_phrases(question, ['что ты умеешь', 'что ты можешь']):
        print('Я только учусь!')
else:
    print('Я тебя не понимаю')
```

Тут видно, что приходится некоторые фразы повторять в нескольких вариантах написания. Чтобы избежать необходимости перечисления всех возможных вариантов, можно использовать проверку фраз через регулярные выражения:

```
import re


def check_phrases(text: str, phrases: list):
    words = re.findall(r"\w+", text.lower())  # получить список слов, без пробелов и знаков препинания

    return any(re.search(phrase, " ".join(words)) is not None for phrase in phrases)


answer = input("Чем Вам помочь?: ")
if check_phrases(answer, ["ни ?чем", "не нужно", "сам справлюсь", "(помоги )?(деньгами|материально)"]):
    print('Ну, тогда до свидания!')
elif check_phrases(answer, ['какой язык (ты )?знаешь', 'на каком языке (ты )?разговариваешь']):
    question = input('Я знаю только "Python". Задавай вопросы: ')
    if check_phrases(question, ['кто тебя (создал|придумал)', 'кто твой создатель']):
        print('Знакомый')
    elif check_phrases(question, ['что (ты )?(умеешь|можешь)']):
        print('Я только учусь!')
    else:
        print('Я тебя не понимаю')
else:
    print('Я тебя не понимаю')
```

Например, в первой фразе бот "поймет" и "ничем", и "ни чем", и "деньгами" или "материально" без "помоги", и с "помоги".

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Уважаемый  @insolor ! Посмотрите, пожалуйста обновлённый вариант моего вопроса.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: спасибо огромное за помощь. А можно как-то решить задачу с помощью более простых способов? Например с помощью вхождения строки в подстроку, используя in.

Comment: Можно, точно так же выносите проверку в отдельную функцию, и так же проверяете как во 2 и 3 примерах.